# Cannot upgrade passenger on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, passenger, apt

Running Apache+Passenger 5.1.12.  Passenger was installed according to the docs for how to install passenger on Apache + Ubuntu 14.04 (via apt).  Apache logs said I should upgrade to 5.3.X.  According to the docs, I should be able to update passenger via `apt-get update`.

I get several `Ign` messages for the passenger repository when running `apt-get update` and no matter what I try, my passenger never updates, it always installs the same version I originally installed (5.1.12).

Are the repositories broken?  Has anyone successfully updated their passenger on Ubuntu 14.04 using apt?

Answer (score 0):

The packages of Ubuntu just contains Passenger [up to 5.0.30](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=passenger), but the [repository of Passenger](https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/) has the version up to 6.0.0, but it seems no Apache plugins in this repo.

I am not so sure if install from that binary or [install from source](https://github.com/phusion/passenger#installing-the-source-directly-from-git) can get any help...

Comment: I installed from source, which worked, but I was hoping to keep using the simpler prescribed method.  Thanks for your help.